# Jmeter is adding an extra space at the end of input parameter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

When I try to add input param in a non-GUI mode in JMeter, it adding an extra space at the end of the variable. There is no space when I enter the params but it is added to the API value when run.

Comment: Show how you send the parameter

Comment: You could trim the value within your test plan

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't "add" or "remove" anything, if there is a "space" - then it's **you** who added it.

JMeter GUI doesn't show whitespaces so you can open the test plan with any text/XML editor of your choice (JMeter's [JMX scripts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) are basically [XML](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/) documents) and see if there is a blank space there.

If the variable comes from an external source ([Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), [CSV File](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) or [Database](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html)) you might want to check it at its source.

Answer (score 0):

[image]this is extremely painful to track-down, for the reasons given.  I had a working JMX, but when clicking in the JMeter GUI, I accidentally appended a space at the end of a variable name; this is within the tabular "User Defined Variables" element.  It slipped past me and, since JMeter does NOT trim that "Name:" field, my variable became "duration " instead of "duration".  Downstream, since the TGs were expecting "${duration}" for "Duration (seconds)", the TG did not execute at all because the variable did not resolve to an integer value.

This seems to be a mistake in the JMeter design.  Simply trimming the variable name, within the GUI commit, would have solved it for me.

What possible value is there to having trailing spaces in a variable name?